# How to trigger some javascript once html (which has been loaded via ajax) loads?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, onload

I'm loading html via ajax and then putting that html into a div. How do I trigger javascript once the html that has been put into the div has been loaded?

I don't know if the onload event is what I'm looking for for this, or if that's even usable with a div element. Keep in mind that this html will be put into the div asynchronously.

EDIT:

the html has an embedded youtube video, so it has to load an image.

Comment: Do you mean you want to know when images and such loads when you put the html in a div.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> How do I trigger javascript once the html that has been put into the div has been loaded?

You just do it after putting the context in the div, in the `onreadystatechange` callback provided by `XMLHttpRequest` (or the "completion" callback provided by whatever library you're using).

E.g.:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(/* ... */);
// ...
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status <= 299) {
        /* ...put the content in the div...*/

        /* ...call your function... */
    }
};
xhr.send();
```

You haven't shown how you're putting the content in the `div`, but it's put there *immediately*, so there's no need for a callback.

---

Some comments have raised a useful question: What about images and such in the content loaded? That's more complicated.

After putting the content in the `div` (let's assume you have the `div` in a variable creatively named `div`), you'd need to know how many incomplete images there were (allowing for the race condition, because although *JavaScript* on browsers is single-threaded, *browsers* are not), and then trigger your code once all the images had loaded.

Something a bit like (assuming this is all in a function, perhaps the `onreadystatechange` handler):

```
var images = div.querySelectorAll('img'),
    img, i, done = false;

for (i = 0; i < images.length; ++i) {
    img = images[i];
    img.onload = img.onerror = checkDone;
}
checkDone();

function checkDone() {
    var x, completed = 0;

    if (done) {
        return;
    }

    for (x = 0; x < images.length; ++x) {
        if (images[x].complete) {
            ++completed;
        }
    }

    if (completed === images.length) {
        done = true;

        /* ...call your "load" function here... */
    }
}
```

Comment: I think OP already knows this since he can put the result in a div.

Comment: What if XMLHttpRequest response contains string like <img src="image.jpg">? It is put in DOM. Stuff is not loaded in this point, even if XMLHttpRequest completion callback has been executed.

Comment: That would certainly be an issue **if** the OP is dealing with images **and** needs to wait for them to finish loading. The question doesn't say anything about that. (Which could just be a failure in the question.)

Comment: I think the question was ok at the first point. OP did not ask how to know when XMLHttpRequest responses.

Comment: @MattiMehtonen: I've addressed images now.